# How do I update a value of a variable after a button is clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def Save():
    save = open("Save1.txt", "w+")
    save.write(str(Coin) + "\n")
    save.write(str(value))
    save.close()

    print("Progress Saved")

SaveBtton = Button(win, text="Save Progress", command=Save)
SaveBtton.place(x=300, y=0)


def Load():
    load = open("Save1.txt", "r")
    Coin = int(load.readline())
    value = int(load.readline())

    print("Progress Loaded")
```

So im trying to update a value of a variable after a button is clicked.
The value of the variable is in another txt file which I need to turn to integer form so that I can use it in my code. but my code is not updating the value of said variable.

any help is appreciated.

Here is the full code:

https://hastebin.com/kagusosiga.py

Comment: Just set `Coin = [your value]` in the `Save` function.

Comment: the thing is, i did that but it didnt work.

Comment: you may need the full code to understand what im doing

Comment: If you are not using `classes`, make `Coin` a `global` variable

Comment: @Debil.exe Then by all means, put the full code. It's hard for us to answer without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did a minute ago.

Answer (score 1):

In a real app, you'd probably persist this state in an object; your `Load` and `Save` functions would be **methods** that share the state via `self`.  The important thing is that the value needs to be available to both functions, and right now when you load it in `Load` it doesn't leave that function.

Here's a very simple non-OOP example, where `Save` and `Load` are both pure functions; `Load` returns the two values, and the caller saves a copy of them to make available to `Save` as parameters:

```
def Load():
    load = open("Save1.txt", "r")
    coin = int(load.readline())
    value = int(load.readline())

    print("Progress Loaded")
    return coin, value

def Save(coin, value):
    save = open("Save1.txt", "w+")
    save.write(str(coin) + "\n")
    save.write(str(value))
    save.close()

    print("Progress Saved")

coin, value = Load()
def save_cmd():
    Save(coin, value)

SaveBtton = Button(win, text="Save Progress", command=save_cmd)
SaveBtton.place(x=300, y=0)
```